# Hiding a button in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to hide a button in WPF used in a Windows form e.g., `button.visible=false`

Is there an equivalent for this in WPF?

Answer (score 68):

Try one of these:

```
button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

`Hidden` hides the button but the button will still take up space in the UI.  `Collapsed` will collapse the button such that it has zero width and height.

Comment: Note that if you are using DataBinding you need to write a ValueConverter that converts the bool to Visibility values.

Comment: Note that if you are using DataBinding you need to write a ValueConverter that converts the bool to Visibility values.

Comment: Such a converter already exists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Comment: To unhide it back, use `button.Visibility =  Visibility.Visible`

Comment: @Jakob , i used your code on button click event , but when i click on button it comes to code(i placed breakpoint there). and after return and there is no change. in short by giving visibility like this , after return design there is no change...

Answer (score 13):

You should set

button.visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

or

button.visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

or by using the WPF XAML property set the same...

Answer (score 5):

`Visibility = Hidden`

Answer (score 3):

If you use the MVVM design pattern, you can make use of the "CanExecute" state of the command that is bound to the button in order to achieve this.

The default behaviour for the button would be to be displayed disabled, but you can change this so it will not be visible using the example below.

**ViewModel**

Property for command property:

```
public DelegateCommand<TypeOfBoundItem> TheCommand
{
    get; private set;
}
```

Instanciate the command (in constructor of view model):

```
TheCommand = new DelegateCommand<TypeOfBoundItem>( Execute, CanExecute );
```

The methods to execute the command and to decide whether it can be executed:

```
private bool CanExecute( TypeOfBoundItem item )
{
    return true or return false;
}

private bool Execute()
{
    // some logic
}
```

**View**

In the resources of the UserControl or Window you define some visibilty converter:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

For the button, you define a binding setting the "Visibility" attribute of the button to the value of the buttons "IsEnabled" state, applying the converter.

So if the "IsEnabled" state is true - because the bound "TheCommand" returns true in its "CanExecute" method - the button will be visible.

If the "CanExecute" method of the bound command returns false, the button will not be visible.

```
<Button Command="{Binding TheCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                             Path=IsEnabled,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</Button>
```