# How to remove/delete a button if a condition is met in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm working on a WinUI 3 application and I have a table with data. On the last column I have a button that says "Update". However I want to remove this button if a condition is met. Right now my button is created on first initialization and then after this condition is checked, it will either stay or be deleted. How can I achieve this behaviour in WinUI 3 application?

Comment: I guess youre question was answered in that post before ... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052593/hiding-a-button-in-wpf)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I checked tom2051's link briefly however haven't had chance to check it fully and apply the code the code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Binding` on the `Visibility` property to display or hide a control conditionally.

```xml
<StackPanel>
   <Button Content="Create" />
   <Button Content="Update"
           Visibility="{Binding CanUpdateVisibility}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here we assume that your `DataContext` is a ViewModel that properly implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a `CanUpdateVisibility` property of type `Visibility`.

If you're not using MVVM, you can also just set your button's `Visibility` to `Visibility.Collapsed` in code behind.